# AutoFill form using Java Swings and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, jtextfield

I am using java swings in this small project of mine.I have four text fields rollno,name,class and section  and the search button.Once I click on the search button(the text fields are empty) I get a list of all table entries(column names same as text fields) from the database in a new table(Using Jtable).This is what I currently have.

Now suppose  I click on one row I want that data to appear in the the text fields with a mouse click,how should I do that?

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SearchResult implements ActionListener{
    JFrame frame,frame1;
    JTextField textbox,textbox1,textbox2,textbox3,textbox4,textbox5,textbox6,textbox7,textbox8;
    JLabel label,label1,label2,label3,label4,label5,label6,label7,label8;
    JButton button;
    JPanel panel;
    static JTable table;

    String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";
    String userName = "root";
    String password = "root";
    String[] columnNames = {"Roll No", "Name", "Class", "Section"};

    public void createUI()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Database Search Result");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        textbox = new JTextField();
        textbox.setBounds(120,30,150,20); 
        label=new JLabel("Roll No.");
        label.setBounds(10, 30, 100, 20);
        textbox1 = new JTextField();
        textbox1.setBounds(120,50,150,20); 
        label1=new JLabel("Name");
        label1.setBounds(10, 50, 100, 20);
        textbox2 = new JTextField();
        textbox2.setBounds(120,70,150,20); 
        label2=new JLabel("Class");
        label2.setBounds(10, 70, 100, 20);
        textbox3 = new JTextField();
        textbox3.setBounds(120,90,150,20); 
        label3=new JLabel("Section");
        label3.setBounds(10, 90, 100, 20);
        button = new JButton("search");
        button.setBounds(120,230,150,20);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        frame.add(textbox);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.add(textbox1);
        frame.add(label1);
        frame.add(textbox2);
        frame.add(label2);
        frame.add(textbox3);
        frame.add(label3);
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500, 400);        
    }   

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        button = (JButton)ae.getSource();
        System.out.println("Showing Table Data.......");
            showTableData();            
    }   

    public void showTableData()
    {

        frame1 = new JFrame("Database Search Result");
        //frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());       
        //TableModel tm = new TableModel();
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);
        //DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(tm.getData1(), tm.getColumnNames());      
        //table = new JTable(model);
        table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(model);      
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);      
        String textvalue = textbox.getText();
        String roll= "";
        String name= "";
        String cl = "";
        String sec = "";
        try
        {           
            Class.forName(driverName);      
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
            //String sql = "select * from student where rollno = "+textvalue;
            String sql="select * from student";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            int i =0;
            while(rs.next())
            {
                roll = rs.getString("rollno");
                name = rs.getString("name");
                cl = rs.getString("class");
                sec = rs.getString("section");                  
                model.addRow(new Object[]{roll, name, cl, sec});

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(),"Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        frame1.add(scroll);
        frame1.setVisible(true);
        frame1.setSize(400,300);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SearchResult sr = new SearchResult();
                sr.createUI();              
    }
}
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class barcoder implements ActionListener{
    JFrame frame,frame1;
    JTextField textbox,textbox1,textbox2,textbox3,textbox4,textbox5,textbox6,textbox7,textbox8;
    JLabel label,label1,label2,label3,label4,label5,label6,label7,label8;
    JButton button;
    JPanel panel;
    static JTable table;

    String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";
    String userName = "root";
    String password = "root";
    String[] columnNames = {"Roll No", "Name", "Class", "Section"};

    public void createUI()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Database Search Result");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        textbox = new JTextField();
        textbox.setBounds(120,30,150,20); 
        label=new JLabel("Roll No.");
        label.setBounds(10, 30, 100, 20);
        textbox1 = new JTextField();
        textbox1.setBounds(120,50,150,20); 
        label1=new JLabel("Name");
        label1.setBounds(10, 50, 100, 20);
        textbox2 = new JTextField();
        textbox2.setBounds(120,70,150,20); 
        label2=new JLabel("Class");
        label2.setBounds(10, 70, 100, 20);
        textbox3 = new JTextField();
        textbox3.setBounds(120,90,150,20); 
        label3=new JLabel("Section");
        label3.setBounds(10, 90, 100, 20);
        button = new JButton("search");
        button.setBounds(120,230,150,20);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        frame.add(textbox);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.add(textbox1);
        frame.add(label1);
        frame.add(textbox2);
        frame.add(label2);
        frame.add(textbox3);
        frame.add(label3);
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500, 400);        
    }   

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        button = (JButton)ae.getSource();
        System.out.println("Showing Table Data.......");
            showTableData();            
    }   

    public void showTableData()
    {

        frame1 = new JFrame("Database Search Result");
        //frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());       
        //TableModel tm = new TableModel();
         DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(){
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) { 
             return false;  
            }
        };
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);
        //DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(tm.getData1(), tm.getColumnNames());      
        //table = new JTable(model);
        table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(model); 
        model.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
            int row = table.getSelectedRow();
            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent arg0) {
                int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                System.out.println("Selecte table row = " + row);
                if (row != -1) {
                    int modelRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
                    System.out.println("Selecte model row = " + row);
                    Vector data = (Vector) ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).getDataVector().get(modelRow);
                    textbox.setText(data.get(0).toString());
                    textbox1.setText(data.get(1).toString());
                    textbox2.setText(data.get(2).toString());
                    textbox3.setText(data.get(3).toString());
                }
            }
        });
        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e) && e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                    if (table.getSelectedRow() != -1) {
                        SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(table).dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);      
        String textvalue = textbox.getText();
        String roll= "";
        String name= "";
        String cl = "";
        String sec = "";
        try
        {           
             Class.forName(driverName);      
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
            //String sql = "select * from student where rollno = "+textvalue;
            String sql="select * from student";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            int i =0;
            while(rs.next())
            {
                roll = rs.getString("rollno");
                name = rs.getString("name");
                cl = rs.getString("class");
                sec = rs.getString("section");                  
                model.addRow(new Object[]{roll, name, cl, sec});

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(),"Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        frame1.add(scroll);
        frame1.setVisible(true);
        frame1.setSize(400,300);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        barcoder sr = new barcoder();
                sr.createUI();              
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selection change can occur for a number of reasons, from the mouse, keyboard or programmatically, for example.

You best choice might be to add a `ListSelectionListener` to the tables selection model and make your changes there.  For example...

```
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        int row = table.getSelectedRow();
        if (row != -1) {
            int modelRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
            Vector data = (Vector)((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).getDataVector().get(modelRow);
        }
    }
});
```

Which will get the column data for a specified row when the selection changes...

Take a look at [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) which provides additional examples

**Updated with working example**

Because I don't have access to your database, I put this simple example together which demonstrates the basic idea

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTable();
    }

    public TestTable() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();

                final JTextField rollField = new JTextField(10);
                final JTextField nameField = new JTextField(10);
                final JTextField classField = new JTextField(10);
                final JTextField sectionField = new JTextField(10);

                JPanel details = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 4));
                details.add(rollField);
                details.add(nameField);
                details.add(classField);
                details.add(sectionField);

                model.setColumnIdentifiers(new String[]{"Roll No", "Name", "Class", "Section"});
                model.addRow(new String[]{"1", "Happy", "Warrior", "Inner"});
                model.addRow(new String[]{"2", "Sad", "Mage", "Outter"});
                model.addRow(new String[]{"3", "Jug Head", "Clown", "Outter space"});

                final JTable table = new JTable(model);
                table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                        int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                        System.out.println("Selecte table row = " + row);
                        if (row != -1) {
                            int modelRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
                            System.out.println("Selecte model row = " + row);
                            Vector data = (Vector) ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).getDataVector().get(modelRow);
                            rollField.setText(data.get(0).toString());
                            nameField.setText(data.get(1).toString());
                            classField.setText(data.get(2).toString());
                            sectionField.setText(data.get(3).toString());
                        }
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(details, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Updated with example overriding `isCellEditable`**

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel() {
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
    }                    
};
```

**Updated with example of closing a window when table is double clicked**

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e) && e.getClickCount() == 2) {
            if (table.getSelectedRow() != -1) {
                SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(table).dispose();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: but then how does the database come into the picture here?

Comment: Why should it? You've already loaded all the values into the table haven't you?

Comment: ok fine,i get your point now..could you please apply it to my code cause I am getting lots of errors?please it would be of great help.

Comment: That'll teach me to type it directly.  Apply the new code to somewhere after `table = new JTable();` and before you add it to the container...

Comment: thank you very much.One last query how to disable the fields in Jtable and once selected how to automatically close the jtable window?

Comment: What do you mean `disable the fields in Jtable`?

Comment: for example right now,once I double click on the row,I can edit that field(I know nothing will get added to the database) but then that doesnt look nice so wanted to disable those cells,I mentioned fields by mistake.

Comment: Ah, okay.  By default `DefaultTableModel` returns `true` from it's `isCellEditable` method.  You need to override this method and return `false`.  You can also use something like `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(table).dispose();` to close a window if you don't have direct access to it

Comment: where do i add SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(table).dispose(); ?

Comment: @overide before the defaulttabelmodel

Comment: Presumably where you want the window to be closed ;)

Comment: the jtable window should be closed once i select a row.

Comment: First, check the update (for disabling cell editing)

Comment: You "could" add it within the `valueChanged` method, but this means as soon as any selection has changed the window will be closed...

Comment: I've added another example of how you might close a window when the user double clicks the table AND a row is selected ;)

Comment: the row gets highlighted and cannot be edited.but no selection is done and text fields dont get populated.

Comment: the close works for me perfect.Only the selection of row doesnt populate the fields.

Comment: I put the updated code.You could try it on yours and see if it works.

Comment: I don't see where you register a `ListSelectionListener`

Comment: DON'T USE `addTableModelListener`, this isn't what you want.  This monitors change to the table, such as when a row is added, delete or updated, NOT when the selection is changed...

Comment: so what should I do,replace addtableModeListener wid listSelectionlistener?

Comment: need little more help from you,wanted to know if its possible to autoresize my jframe depending on which monitor I am using..

Comment: Take a look at [`Frame#setExtendedState`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState(int))

Answer (score 0):

Follow this approach,

On click of row in table, read values of selected row and populate them in corresponding fields.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SearchResult implements ActionListener{
    JFrame frame,frame1;
    JTextField textbox,textbox1,textbox2,textbox3,textbox4,textbox5,textbox6,textbox7,textbox8;
    JLabel label,label1,label2,label3,label4,label5,label6,label7,label8;
    JButton button;
    JPanel panel;
    static JTable table;

    String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";
    String userName = "root";
    String password = "root";
    String[] columnNames = {"Roll No", "Name", "Class", "Section"};

    public void createUI()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Database Search Result");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        textbox = new JTextField();
        textbox.setBounds(120,30,150,20); 
        label=new JLabel("Roll No.");
        label.setBounds(10, 30, 100, 20);
        textbox1 = new JTextField();
        textbox1.setBounds(120,50,150,20); 
        label1=new JLabel("Name");
        label1.setBounds(10, 50, 100, 20);
        textbox2 = new JTextField();
        textbox2.setBounds(120,70,150,20); 
        label2=new JLabel("Class");
        label2.setBounds(10, 70, 100, 20);
        textbox3 = new JTextField();
        textbox3.setBounds(120,90,150,20); 
        label3=new JLabel("Section");
        label3.setBounds(10, 90, 100, 20);
        button = new JButton("search");
        button.setBounds(120,230,150,20);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        frame.add(textbox);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.add(textbox1);
        frame.add(label1);
        frame.add(textbox2);
        frame.add(label2);
        frame.add(textbox3);
        frame.add(label3);
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500, 400);        
    }   

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        button = (JButton)ae.getSource();
        System.out.println("Showing Table Data.......");
            showTableData();            
    }   

    public void showTableData()
    {

        frame1 = new JFrame("Database Search Result");
        //frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());       
        //TableModel tm = new TableModel();
        final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);
        //DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(tm.getData1(), tm.getColumnNames());      
        //table = new JTable(model);
        table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(model); 
        model.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
            int row = table.getSelectedRow();
            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent arg0) {
                int modelRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel(row);

                textbox1.setText(model.getDataVector().get(0).toString());


            }
        });
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);      
        String textvalue = textbox.getText();
        String roll= "";
        String name= "";
        String cl = "";
        String sec = "";
        try
        {           
             Class.forName(driverName);      
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
            //String sql = "select * from student where rollno = "+textvalue;
            String sql="select * from student";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            int i =0;
            while(rs.next())
            {
                roll = rs.getString("rollno");
                name = rs.getString("name");
                cl = rs.getString("class");
                sec = rs.getString("section");                  
                model.addRow(new Object[]{roll, name, cl, sec});

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(),"Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        frame1.add(scroll);
        frame1.setVisible(true);
        frame1.setSize(400,300);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SearchResult sr = new SearchResult();
                sr.createUI();              
    }
}
```

Comment: But how do I do that?Could you help me with that?

Comment: Try out this code, I know it's not perfectly what you want. But does most of things you expect.

Comment: thanks for the code.It gets selected but it doesnt populate the text fields on selection.

Comment: Getting values from DB part was commented, code is modified in post. Checked same code on my side, it populates value of selected row in Name text field.

Comment: `TableModelListener` relates to changes in the model (like add, removing or editing rows), not changes in the view state (such as selection).  Your example will only ever provide information about a single row, as `row` is never updated...

Comment: there is some problem with my eclipse,will check and let you know soon.It was running my old code

Comment: working almost...just could you tell me what is get(0) in 
 textbox1.setText(model.getDataVector().get(0).toString());

Comment: model.getDataVector() gives you value of selected row in form of Vector, thereafter you can read contents from vector and set them on corresponding text fields. Let me know if you require any further help.

Comment: how to disable the cells in Jtable and once selected how to automatically close the jtable window?

Comment: Change TableModel declaration with this code,                                              final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(){
         @Override
         public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            //all cells false
            return false;
             }
        
        };

Comment: @user2958963 Please upvote the answer, if you feel it's worth.

Comment: but when I double click I dont get my selection in the text fields?

Comment: For that you need to write some logic in public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent arg0) {}